# Antd table is not updating on dataSource updates/changes

Tags: antd

```
<Table
     columns={columnsStructure}
     dataSource={source}
     pagination={pagination}
     onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

the source is an array of objects. On component mount Table is rendering properly but once datSource i.e. source is updated, table rows remain the same.

How to resolve this issue. Wanted to update ant design table on source update.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To resolve this Ant-Design table data auto-update issue, you have to pass the data-source value as a clone of the observable value. like

```
<Table
     columns={columnsStructure}
     dataSource={[...source]}
     pagination={pagination}
     onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: While this solution will work, it's ideal to update the `source` state using this "deep copy" method.

Comment: This is still not working for me. I see redux state has the updated values but antd table is still the same

Comment: It works for me, I'm using form value instead of creating a state in react, it saves a lot of performances issues

Comment: this does not work for me, have you guys found another solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

This is a trap of shallow comparison.

If you reused the objects in the oldDataSource to increase efficiency, like:

```
const newDataSource=[...oldDataSource]
newDataSource[0].column1="newValue"
setDatasource(newDataSource)
```

This will not work.
Yes, the table is updating, because you have a new list. However, the list components inside the table are not updating, because they see the old objects (although you changed the value).
To make it work you need to do:

```
const newDataSource=[...oldDataSource]
newDataSource[0]={...newDataSource[0], column1: "newValue"}
setDatasource(newDataSource)
```

Then that row will update.

Answer (score 3):

The above solution did not work for me. I found that since the 'key' property of the row objects is remaining the same, React was not picking up the change.

What worked for me, though a bit hacky is generating a random key when a row object is changed. Hopefully the key is not being used for anything other than React to keep track of it, which is what it's usually meant for.

```
 const updatedEntry = {
    ...record,
    key: (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7),
    //anyproperty : //yourValue
      }
```

Still looking for more cleaner solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this Ant-Design table data auto-update issue, you have to pass the data-source value as a clone of the observable value. like

```
var _ = require('lodash');
...
<Table
     columns={columnsStructure}
     dataSource={_.cloneDeep(sources)}
     pagination={pagination}
     onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: Bro thanks so much, this works and is easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Add render in columns

```
{
   title: "amount",
   dataIndex: "amount",
   key: "amount",
   render: (amount) => (amount),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue when working with `MobX` and `antd`. For me working wrap array from store into `computed`

```
const documentsData = computed(() => managementStore.documentFiles).get()

<Table
    bordered
    size="large"
    dataSource={documentsData}
    columns={columns}
    pagination={false}
  />
```